# How to get a text from a dynamic HTML tag

Tags: c#, html, web-crawler

How I can extract only `ARTS 003` from the following html script. In the following script `<a href= *** target="_blank">ARTS 003</a>` which the `***` is the dynamic part and can change from one to another page. FYI, I have a few html pages.

```
<a href="preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=2&coid=1380" onclick="acalogPopup('preview_course.php?catoid=2&coid=1380&print', '3', 770, 530, 'yes');return false;" rel="remote /ajax/preview_course.php?catoid=2&coid=1380&display_options[location]=tooltip&show" id="tt2379" target="_blank">ARTS 003</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using Html Agility Pack, http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution using pure JavaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/ay284ktk/

```
    <a id="mylink" href="preview_course_nopop.php?catoid=2&coid=1380" onclick="acalogPopup('preview_course.php?catoid=2&coid=1380&print', '3', 770, 530, 'yes');return false;" rel="remote /ajax/preview_course.php?catoid=2&coid=1380&display_options[location]=tooltip&show"
id="tt2379" target="_blank">ARTS 003</a>

var myel = document.getElementById('mylink');
alert(myel.textContent);
```

Solution: you can attribute an id to the `<a>` tag and then get the textContent.
Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @estevanj. I had the following script `MatchCollection prereq = Regex.Matches(html, @"<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>", RegexOptions.Singleline);  foreach (Match ID in prereq)
                    {
                        string Pre = ID.Groups[1].Value;
                        UNI[row, 3] = Pre;
                    }` Then how I can replace your code with mine?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery .txt() function. Something like this:

```
var txt = $('a').txt();
```

or

```
var txt = $('a[id^="tt"]').txt();
```